# Set label for a custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have a custom table cell and I'm just trying to set the label, image, etc but for some reason it's not working.

Here is my code for my custom cell

BrowserMenuCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BrowseMenuCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *wishListBUtton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *itemImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *itemLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *itemPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *quantityField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *totalLabel;
- (IBAction)plusButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cartButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)minusButton:(id)sender;
@end
```

BrowserMenuCell.m

```
#import "BrowseMenuCell.h"

@implementation BrowseMenuCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (IBAction)plusButton:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)cartButton:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)minusButton:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Cell for row at index path

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BrowseMenuCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemsCell"];
    OfficeSupply *supply = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray * views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BrowseMenuCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id obj in views){
            if([obj isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                BrowseMenuCell * obj = [[BrowseMenuCell alloc]init];
                obj.itemLabel.text = supply.itemName;
                cell = obj;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Delete this line: BrowseMenuCell * obj = [[BrowseMenuCell alloc]init]; and try again

Comment: Then I can't set the itemLabel.text

Comment: The way I fixed it was just by  UILabel     *name  = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:6]; but don't know if that is the right way.

Comment: Did you set the custom cell's class in the xib ? And did you properly linked the IBOutlets ?

Answer (score 0):

To start with, don't create a new random instance of the cell after you have already created one from the NIB file. Change the code to this:

```
    for (BrowseMenuCell *obj in views){
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[BrowseMenuCell class]])
        {
            obj.reuseIdentifier = @"ItemsCell";
            obj.itemLabel.text = supply.itemName;
            cell = obj;
            break;
        }
    }
```

That won't guarantee it works, but at least the NIB setup of your labels won't be getting thrown away.

If it still doesn't work. Debug. Check the frames of the labels. Check the label references are set (not nil).

Comment: Which indicates that your XIB property references are incorrectly (or probably not) connected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [self.tableView reloadData]?

Comment: My table loads, it's just that the label doesn't set.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way you create cell. Try this one:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BrowseMenuCell *cell = (BrowseMenuCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemsCell"];
    OfficeSupply *supply = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (_cellObj == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BrowseMenuCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    }

   cell.itemlabel.text = supply.itemName;

    return cell;
}
```