# Cannot set properties on custom table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem settings my view elements on a custom cell. The table cells appear in my tableView, but the properties do not set and thus only empty/blank cells appear.

The tableView is not a tableView controller, but only a tableView in a viewController.

I have the following files:

**CustomCell.xib:**
Here i use IB to build the custom cell by using a Table View Cell from object library with labels and images on. I set the Identifier as *orderListCell*. From this screen I ctrl+drag to create the outlets in *customCell.h*

**CustomCell.h**
Here I see all my IBOutlets as properties from above mentioned file

**CustomCell.m**
Here I leave as is

**OrderListViewController.h**
Here I import *customCell.h* and use protocols *UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource*

**OrderListViewController.m**
Here I set my tableView delegate and tableView dataSource to self. I also create an IBOutlet for my tableView from the Storyboard.

I use the following code to try and display my cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"orderListCell";

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[CustomCell  alloc] init];
}

 cell.myLabel.text = @"aaaaaaaa"; //[[self.orders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"tableNo"];



return cell;
}
```

I have simplified my code a bit to demonstrate that even setting the label to a simple string (@"aaaaaaaa") doesnt work. When I look at the objects in my debugger the cell does have all the properties from the IBOutlets and the cell does appear in my tableView, just the *label.text = xxx* does not seem to work.

I have looked at the following posts but either dont understand it properly or it does not work for me:

[ios 7 customizing UITableViewCell's content view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196868/ios-7-customizing-uitableviewcells-content-view)
[Can't set properties in Custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057408/cant-set-properties-in-custom-uitableviewcell)
[Set label for a custom cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052208/set-label-for-a-custom-cell)

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cell = [[CustomCell  alloc] init];` does not create your cell from the XIB, so none of the XIB content will be created.

Use `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` to register the XIB with the table view so that it will create your cell instances for you (you don't need to create instances yourself in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`).

If you don't want to do that, you can load your NIB explicitly with `nibWithNibName:bundle:` and `instantiateWithOwner:options:`, then get the cell instance from the list of returned views (which should only contain 1 item).

Comment: Wow this issue really frustrated the life out of me. Your response put me on the right track and after some research and trial and error I finally figured it out. Before using registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: one first need to create the nib using [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCellName" bundle:nil] and then use that in the first mentioned method. Thanks very much!